# How to get rid of "Source" label aside the Source button of CKeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

I would like to keep this button in the toolbar, keep its actions unchanged, keep the tooltip appear, but limit the *label* property to the tooltip only.

Inside the *a.ui.addButton("Source"...* of *CKEDITOR.plugins.add("sourcearea",...* in the `ckeditor.js`, the `label` option is defined like in the the other plugins that receive no permanent label on the toolbar. Tried

```
a.ui.addButton("Source", {
                        label: "",
                        command: "source",
                        toolbar: "mode,10"
                    });
```

which doesn't satisfy me 100%, as the tooltip is also removed.

CKEditor 4.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue just by styling, maybe this could help you, if you still didn't figured out how this could be done

```css
span.cke_button__source_label {
  display: none;
}
```